# how to query all rows above a specific date in sqflite

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I have a column with dates and time looking like `2021-08-19 04:15:53.990179`.

the package is sqflite with flutter

I am trying to query everything in the table above a specific date

this is my query

```
'SELECT * FROM table WHERE strftime("%Y-%m-%d", <column_name>) >= <specific_date>'
```

can someone kindly spot what's wrong in this

Comment: Is it giving any error?

Comment: nope, its just returning empty array